# One-point function in CFT on an infinite strip through scaling analysis

Tags: conformal-field-theory, boundary-conditions, correlation-functions, scaling

In Philippe Di Francesco's [book](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4612-2256-9) on Conformal Field Theory in section 11.2.3 on the Infinite Strip, the one point function of a primary operator (with scaling dimension $\Delta$) is calculated by considering a conformal mapping from the upper half plane.
For an infintie strip of width L this is found to be:
$$ \langle \Phi (w,\bar{w}) \rangle_{strip} = \left(\frac{2iL}{\pi} \right)^{\Delta} \frac{1}{[\sin(\pi v /L)]^{\Delta}} $$

With $w = u + iv$ and $u$ being the longitudinal coordinate and $v$ the transverse. In the limit $v << L$  we have
$$\langle \Phi (v) \rangle_{strip} \propto \frac{1}{v^\Delta} [1 + \frac{1}{6}\pi^2 \Delta (v/L)^2 + ...  ] $$

The book then states that this is compatible with the more general result of Fisher and de Gennes obtained through a scaling analysis in dimension $d$:

$$\langle \Phi (v) \rangle_{strip} \sim \frac{1}{v^\Delta} [1 + const.(v/L)^d + ...  ] $$

My question is what is the derivation of this general result. The only Fisher and de Gennes paper that I was able to find was [this](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k62353730/f61.image) paper from 1978 written in French. I am unable to understand the text and the equations there don't appear to be very relevant. I would be grateful if someone could provide a detailed derivation of this general result.

Answer (score 1):

I believe Fisher and de Gennes in the paper you link only conjecture the result (and only explicitly for d = 3). See below:

[image]

I'm not sure one can give a general proof. Even some more recent papers, such as this one: https://arxiv.org/abs/1503.00254 still state the Fisher-de Gennes scaling as an ansatz. Although, like in the proof you gave for d = 2, maybe one can use some universal form of the one-point function?